# php mongodb extension not working in windows 10

Tags: php, apache, php-mongodb

These are the files I downloaded.

> apache==>>httpd-2.4.32-Win64-VC15
>   **(x64 VC15)**
>
> PHP==>>php-7.2.3-Win32-VC15-x64
>   **(x64 VC15 Thread Safe)**
>
> php_mongodb.dll==>>php_mongodb-1.4.2-7.2-ts-vc15-x64
>   **(x64 VC15 Thread Safe)**

**steps i did**

**1.** extracted apache to "C:\Apache24"

**2.** added to Windows environment variables path "C:\Apache24\bin" and installed it as a service httpd -k install

**3.** extracted php to "C:php"

**4.** renamed php.ini-development to php.ini

**5.** added lines

> LoadModule php7_module "c:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"

SetHandler application/x-httpd-php

PHPIniDir "c:/php"

**6.** extracted php_mongodb.dll to "c:/php/ext/"

**7.** added line "extension=php_mongodb.dll" in "c:/php/php.ini" just after ";extension=xsl" without ";"

**8.** added "C:\php" to PATH

**MongoDB shell version v3.6.3**

mongodb module is not shown in phpinfo() but its shown in cli "php -m"

[image]

[image]

tried a sample script which runs perfectly in my ubuntu system along with the mongo library downloaded with composer

```
<?php
session_start();
require "vendor/autoload.php";
$conn=new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");

$coll=$conn->sims->users;
$result = $coll->find( [ 'username' => 'david' ] );

foreach ($result as $entry) {
echo $entry['_id'], ': ', $entry['username'], "\n";
}
?>
```

I get a Fatal error as expected (since php_mongodb is not working)

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in C:\Apache24\htdocs\SIMS_SSS\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Client.php:61 Stack trace: #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\SIMS_SSS\authenticate.php(4): MongoDB\Client->__construct('mongodb://local...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\SIMS_SSS\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Client.php on line 61

Comment: I am the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @ÖzgürCanKaragöz No I haven't , I migrated my work to "ubuntu". PHPmongo driver is working fine in ubuntu. I had some problems with 18LTS so I rolled back to 16LTS. Everythings going good so far and no luck in windows till now :(